# Read the Apple ID out of my iOS App

Tags: ios, app-store, data-protection

I wouldlike to know if it is possible to read out the apple id or any personal data from the mobile phone?

We are planning to create a sensitive data app for clients and we wouldlike to assure them that we arent aware about the apple id or any other sensitiv data.

Does someone has expirience with this?

Best regards
Rayk

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you call sensitive data? Because the system is fully locked you know

Comment: The problem with this question is that answering with "there is no way" is like declaring a scientific theory true - you can only refute it, never prove it. The best you can do is rely on official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no way** to get users Apple ID from an iOS app, Apple is all about privacy and the last thing they want to do is share users Apple ID with anyone